# htop and crontab

Tags: terminal, cron, xterm, htop

I have a crontab like this for root user:

```
9 17 * * * TERM=xterm /bin/bash /root/htop_stat.sh
```

`htop_stat.sh`:

```
/usr/bin/echo q | /usr/bin/htop -C | /usr/bin/aha --line-fix | /usr/bin/html2text -width 999 | /usr/bin/grep --line-buffered -v "F1Help\|xml version=" > /tmp/htop.txt
```

If I manually run `htop_stat.sh` as root, it works fine.

However, when the above cronjob kicks in, htop.txt only has the first 23 lines of htop's output.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you try to remove set of TERM in cron?

Comment: Yes, I actually started without and it would make `/tmp/htop.txt` empty because `htop` relies on the environment variable `TERM`.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you consider using `top`, `ps`? `htop` by definition is "interactive process viewer"

Comment: `htop` gives me a bit more detail about all the processes.  That's why I choose `htop` instead.  And yes, `htop` is interactive.  But what I don't get is, "bash htop_stat.sh > /tmp/htop.txt" works perfectly.

Comment: It work fine because when you open terminal you have `TERM` variable set. Which is not the case with cron. In your shell script exec something like: `stty rows 50 cols 132` before the command and check the result

Comment: @RomeoNinov right, that's why I tried to set `TERM` to `xterm`.  Without that (as you suggested), `htop` in my script won't work at all -- outputting nothing.  I just tried to put your `stty` the first line in my script but it still outputted only 23 lines.  Thought?

Answer (score 2):

The prefix `TERM=xterm` is not allowed for a cron command, it is not a shell prompt.

Either put it as a separate line in the crontab file:

```
TERM=xterm
9 17 * * * /bin/bash /root/htop_stat.sh
```

or include it in your `htop_stat.sh`.

See `man 5 crontab` for details.

Comment: Thanks! You are indeed right that environment variable should be in a separate line per manpage. Tho, it is weird that putting in a separate line also has the same result as putting it in the same line preceding to the command.

Comment: I think why environment variable can be set preceding my script.  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856129/setting-an-environment-variable-before-a-command-in-bash-not-working-for-second)